# How can I change username of users in dhis2?

Tags: dhis-2

I have approximately 500 users of my dhis2 clone system, Where i need to change username of at least 400 users but when I opens Edit user window there is no option to do so, Can anyone help **How can I update username of user in dhis2?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found solution of above problem myself, Posting answer here so that it may help others in future.

Answer: go to users list, click on an item, select replicate option, change username and password, New User will be created with new credentials.

**Note: All other settings will remain same.**

Now you can delete old user.